# Find the area problem from the calcbook #1910

Tags: calculus

Find the area bounded by these formulas: $y=e^{3x}$, $y=8$ and $x=\ln 3$

the biggest problem is that $e^{3x}>0$, which means that the area should come out to infinity.

---

After graphing the problem correctly, many thanks for the answers. 
[image]

I get the integral $$\int\limits_{\ln(2)}^{\ln(3)} e^{3x}-8\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Sketch a graph to see that the area is not infinite.

Comment: @MaoYiyi Your biggest problem is solved by the lines $y=8$ and $x=\ln (3)$.

Comment: The fact that $\forall x\in\mathbf R,e^{3x}>0$ is not reason enough for the area to be infinite. Example: $\forall x\in\mathbf R,e^{-x^2}>0$ but $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx=\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: Michael Corleone that is a different case. In this case, if not for the line $y=8$ and/or $x=ln3$ surely the area could have been at infinity.

Comment: @YYG You are right. I was thinking the question meant to consider the region under the line $y=8$ and left of the line $x=\ln(3)$.

Comment: @MichaelCorleone, yea you are not the only one, most of people thought it that way. Perhaps the question is not much clear until the author elaborated it to someone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot corresponding to this question is

[image]

so the area is not infinite.

In particular, the area is
$$\int_a^{\ln(3)} (e^{3x}-8)\,dx$$
where $a$ is the value of $x$ at which the curves $y=e^{3x}$ (red) and $y=8$ (green) cross, which has been denoted by the dashed gray line. You've correctly calculated that $a=\ln(2)$ because
$$e^{3a}=8\implies 3a=\ln(8)=3\ln(2)\implies a=\ln(2).$$

---

*Mathematica* code:

```
Show[
Plot[E^(3 x), {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, AxesStyle -> Directive[13,
FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], 

RegionPlot[y > 8 && y < E^(3 x) && x < Log[3], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 40},
PlotPoints -> 100], 

Plot[E^(3 x), {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, AxesStyle -> Directive[13,
FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],

Plot[8, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Darker[Green]}], 

ParametricPlot[{Log[3], t}, {t, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], 

ParametricPlot[{Log[8]/3, t}, {t, 0, 8}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Gray, Dashed}]]
```

The red graph is repeated because the `RegionPlot` covers over the lines slightly, but the `Show` command implements whatever styles for the composite image come from the first plot, and I didn't like how the `RegionPlot` affected things, so a shortcut / hack was to put a plot before it, then put it again after it.

Comment: two questions 1) how did you make that nice graph?! 2) from the answer in the book I have the correct integral, because it has to be bounded area by the equations given.  It doesn't state that x is greater than zero. Really, how did you make that awesome graph!

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Aha, I see that both YYG and I have been misinterpreting the question as having mistakenly left out the restriction that $x>0$, but really the question is asking about the triangular shape *above* the line $y=8$! I'll edit my answer to include the correct graph, as well as the *Mathematica* code for it.

Comment: @MaoYiyi and Zev Chonoles: am not trying to argue, but if you look at my answer very well you can notice that I didn't misinterpret any part in MaoYiyi's  question. Thanks.

Comment: @YYG: When you say "bounded from the up", I understand that as meaning "bounded from above", i.e. the region is *below* the referenced curve. This is not correct (but I made the same mistake too).

Comment: Okay, am sorry for the English, but I meant "upward" else I should have said "from above". Thanks.

Comment: @yyg no worries, my English is horrible, I often make mistakes trying to understand problems here.

Answer (score 0):

No, the area can never be at infinity as it is bounded by the line $y=8$ upward and from the left by the line $x=ln3$

Comment: This does not really suffice as an answer. The region bounded from above by $y=8$ and from the left by $x=\ln(3)$, with no further restrictions, i.e. the set
$$\{(x,y)\mid x<\ln(3)\text{ and }y<8\},$$ **does** have infinite area. Even the region bounded from above by $y=8$, from below by $y=0$, and from the left by $x=\ln(3)$ has infinite area. The problem depends in an essential way on the properties of the exponential function.

Comment: Probably you don't know what I mean by "bounded..." in this context.